# Why are these two Numpy arrays of different shapes?

Tags: numpy-ndarray

Consider,

```py
import numpy as np

Wb = np.array([
    np.empty(3, dtype=np.ndarray),
    np.empty(3, dtype=np.ndarray)
], dtype=np.ndarray)

print(Wb.shape)  # (2, 3)

Wb = np.empty(2, dtype=np.ndarray)
Wb[0] = np.empty(3, dtype=np.ndarray)
Wb[1] = np.empty(3, dtype=np.ndarray)

print(Wb.shape)  # (2,)
```

With the first way, I initialise `Wb` with a list of the same elements I assign manually in the second way. Should the shapes of final `Wb` be different? Why?